# Restore windows 7 image from USB (without cd rom)

Tags: windows-7, boot

I am having hard time in restoring windows 7 image to my new SSD. I do not have Cd/dvd drive. I have made bootable windows 7 usb and when I try to restore image from startup repair it asks me to put repair disk (it only prompts for cd drive).

I tried clonedrive to clone my all drives but windows shows me blue screen, repaired several time windows and now I getting error startup repair can't repair your computer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your existing installation is really messed up, why bother cloning? Also, if the SSD is replacing an HDD, a clean install is highly recommended. You should be able to pull your data from the old drive using any LiveCD/USB.

Comment: Existing installation is fine, I kept windows installation for three years. I have so many softwares and configuration set up and I can't afford to lose it.

Comment: "now I getting error startup repair can't repair your computer" - Made me think the existing installation is broken beyond repair. Anyway, try something like Acronis True Image or Norton Ghost for cloning instead of "clonedrive" (whatever that is).